# Updating images on openlayers map

Tags: refresh, openlayers

I have a function:

```
function images_styles(Isel){
    if (Isel==1){
        var marker_pic="/sites/all/themes/shakhty/images/map/icons/1.png";
    }
    else{
        var marker_pic="http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png";
    }
    var styleImage = new OpenLayers.Style({
        graphicWidth: 43,  
        graphicHeight: 65,  
        graphicYOffset: -28,              
        label: "${label}",   
        externalGraphic: marker_pic,   
        fontSize: "1em",
        strokeOpacity:5
    });

    var vectorImage = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Images", {
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({ 
            "default": styleImage
        })
    });


    map.addLayer(vectorImage);
}
```

I want to change images (marker_pic) when user chooses variant in form. But when the variant has choosen for the first time, the image doesn't change, until i reload page.

What should i do?

How to refresh images every time user choose another variant?

Answer (score 0):

To update your vector layer with a new external graphic, try the following:

```
vectorImage.refresh({force:true});
```

Alternatively, the following should work as well:

```
vectorImage.redraw();
```